# Dymola: Avoid "Not enough storage for initial variable data" for large Modelica model

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am trying to simulate a large Modelica model in Dymola. This model uses several records that define time series input data (data with 900 second intervals for 1 year), which it reads via the `CombiTimeTable` model.

If I limit the records to only contain the data for 2 weeks (also 900 second intervals), the model simulates fine.

With the yearly data, the translation seems to run successfully, but simulation fails. The `dslog` file contains the message `Not enough storage for initial variable data`.

This happens on a Windows 10 system with 8 GB RAM as well as on a Windows 7 system with 32 GB RAM.

Is there any way to avoid this error and get the simulation to run? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recommended way is to have the time series data not within the records (that is in your model or library) but as external data files. The [CombiTimeTable](http://doc.modelica.org/om/Modelica.Blocks.Sources.CombiTimeTable.html) supports both reading from text file and MATLAB MAT file at simulation run-time. You will also benefit from shorter translation times.

You still can organize your external files relative to your library by means of Modelica URIs since the CombiTimeTable (as well as the other [table blocks](http://doc.modelica.org/om/Modelica.Blocks.Tables.html)) already call the [loadResource](http://doc.modelica.org/om/Modelica.Utilities.Files.loadResource.html) function. The recommended way is to organize these files in an Resources directory of your Modelica package.